# Preposition usage - the taxes they paid can be used [on] the health care system?

Tags: prepositions

> Countries that are facing population ageing should encourage
>   immigration. An aging population means that there are more retired
>   people and there are fewer people working and paying taxes. As a
>   result, working adults need to pay more taxes to the government. If
>   more people immigrate to these countries, there will be a larger
>   working population and the taxes they pay can be used **on** the
>   health care system and to improve the infrastructures in these
>   countries.

Is the use of **on** correct in the above sentence?

I wrote this so there is no source for it.

Comment: Suggestion: Would you please add the source?

Comment: *For* is better. *On* is idiomatic but not a very good idiom.

Comment: @Cardinal Sorry, I should have that I wrote it.

Comment: Typo: you mean to say "if more people *immigrate*" and "the taxes they *pay*"  or *have paid*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ent to keep your sentence as it is, "taxes used for" is the more natural expression. Taxes used on would be understood but would be a less common choice:

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taxes%20used%20on%2Ctaxes%20used%20for&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaxes%20used%20for%3B%2Cc0) *taxes used on* vs *taxes used for*

From [Taxes Information](https://books.google.it/books?id=fQuudROnzfoC&q=%22taxes%20used%20for%22&dq=%22taxes%20used%20for%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNwNuKubnPAhXKLMAKHcUEAVAQ6AEIHzAB):

> - What are these ***taxes used for and how*** are they collected? Answer—Federal income taxes provide operating funds for various programs and services...

From [Earth at crossroads](https://books.google.it/books?id=vDTVnqQWyuAC&pg=PA219&dq=%22taxes%20used%20for%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXi9z0ubnPAhUIBsAKHX8sAaYQ6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=%22taxes%20used%20for%22&f=false):

> - ***Some of the taxes used for financing the system*** are: carbon tax (on fossil fuels), nitrogen tax (to encourage efficient use of fertilizers and use of nitr

Comment: Thank you! I don't have to keep it as it is, what are some other ways to express this meaning?

Comment: You can use *spent on*. That would be fine.

Comment: Nice avatar! But the username is a bit of a misnomer. :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - I think it is in line with the spirit of the site:)